# Do 6-way corner brackets exist?

Tags: walls, framing, structural, post, steel

I'm trying to mount a 2x2" horizontal cross for guy lines to a central vertical 2x2" post.

Forgive my 3d art, but here's a picture.  Each post intersects at the same point and all posts are 2x2" common board.  The vertical post is much taller than drawn, the lower vertical close is closer the ground. The smaller posts that point to the sides are shorter for mounting guy lines at a distance from the peak (to control sway with 4x taughtline hitches):

[image: 6-way corner post]

I've found things like 5-way post corners or 3-way corners, but nothing for a 6-way intersection.

I could use a bunch of angle brackets, but was envisioning a single bracket that looked like this, so the vertical would go through the center square and the side spars would lay in the slots:

[image: 6-way corner bracket]

It looks like something Simpson Strong Tie would fold up, but I've not seen anything.

Ideas?

Comment: a hexagon ..........

Comment: I think most strong tie type stuff is cut and folded out of flat sheets of metal and that would have to be welded.  It would also be specific to 2x2 lumber and they're not going to make reinforcement brackets for 2x2s.  Between those two factors, I don't think you'll find anything like that.

Comment: you could get some 1-1/2" x 1-1/2" square steel tubing, cut the pieces and have a shop weld that hedgehog together for you maybe?

Comment: Maybe expand what you want it for.  2x2s usually do not need guy wires, and if you need guy wires, why are you using 2x2s.  Can usually break 2x2s with my foot to make small pieces for burning.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory, I think it could be folded from a flat sheet if mount points were tabs, but after some digging I think that two orthogonal [double-wing 90-degree corner fittings](https://www.amazon.com/Double-Connector-Fitting-Channel-Thickness/dp/B0B5QTLYSS) would work.  I just didn't know what to search for when I started the question.

Comment: also @crip569 makes a good point about not making steel bracing for 2x2's, it doesn't make sense for the general case.  This is for an antenna mast so its long and flimsy, but not super heavy.  The guy lines just keep it strait so it doesn't lean.

Comment: @Ruskes, perhaps my 3d looks too 2D... its not _supposed_ to be a hexagon! lol.  But yes, its shadow would look very hexagonal...

Comment: For antenna masts there usually are some guy wire holders/attachment points made for the masts.  Most antenna masts are round posts, so this seems homemade, if using square tubing.

Comment: I found 5 way and need to add the 6th

Comment: I'm curious as to what your use case is.

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't be easier to do this with PVC pipe instead?  You can get straighter longer pieces of that than spruce 2x2s for one thing.

Comment: You speak of 2x2s but the use case and drawings suggest metal construction. There are woodworking joints that can be cut to make such a connection, but I'm not sure that 2x2s will be strong enough for this application.

Comment: @gnicko, metal bracing but wood construction (2x2's = 1.5x1.5" common board).

Comment: @Huesmann its to mount [this antenna](https://youtu.be/Ab_oJHlENwo) for [contacting the ISS](https://youtu.be/_LG5urNUqg4)